# What classes and methods are not in a python test suite, statically?

Tags: python, testing, abstract-syntax-tree, static-code-analysis

Say that `file.py` has class `C` with methods `M1 M2` ...,
but `test/*.py` never calls `C` at all, or never calls `M2`.
Is there a **static** program analysis tool
that detects this, and writes a list of
apparently unused classes / unused methods ?

(Sure, dynamic Python can easily defeat static analysis, but static analysis may still be useful.
Finding class names not in `test/*.py` is trivial, a bash one-liner,
and indeed finds some (non-base classes) in anon.
Finding a never-called `Cinstance.method`, though, would I guess require
[ast](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) or the like.)

Comment: the term you are looking for is 'coverage report' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage

Comment: Thanks, but that looks dynamic ?

Comment: Yes, because that's a vastly superior approach to the problem, even in more static languages. The information is several orders of magnitude more fine-grained and much more accurate. Why are you asking for a static approach?

Comment: @delnan, because static analysis is fast, no runs at all, and looks easy. What's "more accurate" than "fgrep -w Classname test/*py" is nil ?

Comment: More accurate in several dimensions: Fewer to none false positives (this encompasses a slew of issues like dead code, complicated control flow, and indirect references), fewer to none false negatives (see previous aside), can distinguish between "class is referred to" and "class is actually used", etc. "no runs" is not important IMHO -- you run only the tests (which you already have), which you should be able to run at any time and place, and very quickly too (which calls the performance argument into question too).

Comment: Don't forget false positives in comments